# Use REST API with hadoop's HDFS

Tags: java, rest, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

Let's say I have one Text File (Size 1 GB). I want to search particular word from file and if it is found the Line number should be returned.

I can Execute my java program using command line in linux. But what I want is some Interface using REST API.

When I submit that word in GUI(My Interface) and submit request it should be able to call HDFS , commands should be provided by itself and it should return me the result.

How Can you approach this problem ? (I have very primitive knowledge about REST API)

Referred

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#ParameterDictionary[]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YcW25PHnAA